# Altering Spring security 3.1 custom login standard names

Tags: spring-security

I am using spring security 3.1 with Hibernate and used  a Custom UserdetailsService class and a custom login page  for authentication.

Question is how can I get rid of using the standard spring security naming conventions in login form,

`j_spring_security_check`,
`j_spring_security_logout`,
`j_username` – Username,
`j_password` – Password

and use alternatives.

Spring security docs says that it is not a good practice to reveal these details.But I couldn't find any example on how to use custom urls for this purpose.

It will be greatly appreciated if someone could provide an example implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are configured in `<form-login>` and `<logout>` attributes:

```
<form-login username-parameter="" password-parameter="" login-processing-url="" />
<logout logout-url="" />
```

See the documentation: http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#nsa-http-children.